# Clear Datepicker's value after clicking the submit button in xamarin form

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker

My problem is, the data which is date entered by user is doesn't after submit button. So I have fields in my registration page and A button to save in my database.
This is what I've tried.
//My Datepicker Design
`

```
<local:BirthdayDatePickerControl
                                                        TextColor="Black"
                                                      x:Name="entryField_DateOfBirth"
                                                      />
```

`

The purpose that I create a custom control in my datepicker is to put an placeholder iny my datepicker field.
//my Birthdaypickercontrol.cs
`

```
 public class BirthdayDatePickerControl : DatePicker
    {
        public event EventHandler ClearRequested;
        
        // for my placeholder "birthdate"
            public static readonly BindableProperty EnterTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Placeholder", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(BirthdayDatePickerControl), defaultValue: default(string));
            public string Placeholder { get; set; }
        
        //function to clear data of my datepicker input
        public void clear()
        {
            if (ClearRequested != null)
            {
                ClearRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

`

In my project.android, I create a birthday renderer.cs
//so this is my code
`

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BirthdayDatePickerControl), typeof(BirthdayDatePickerRenderer))]
  public class BirthdayDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        public BirthdayDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        EditText editText;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
           //code for placeholder
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Text = "Birth Date";
            }
            //end here

            //code  start here for clearing the data in datepicker input field
            editText = Control as EditText;
            if (e.NewElement != null)  
            {
                BirthdayDatePickerControl bdaydatePickerControl = e.NewElement as BirthdayDatePickerControl;
                 bdaydatePickerControl.ClearRequested += DatePickerControl_ClearRequested;
           
            }
            //end here
          
        }

        public void DatePickerControl_ClearRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            editText.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

`
The codes I pasted will anyway, but..
Assuming in the onload of my registration page, [The UI will be like this( pic for reference and ctto to google)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X2w4.png). After user choose birthdate, example 12/1/22 and hit submit button(all data save in to database). The problem is the placeholder "birthdate" remove/disappear [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dm29.png), then if I click the datepicker input field to check the date, the date is still pointing in 12/1/22. What I expected is after performing the ClearData(), the date should be reset in today's date.

//this is my ClearData() function
`

```
public void ClearData()
        {
            entryField_DateOfBirth.clear();// this is what I tried and got an bad ouput


}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> What I expected is after performing the ClearData(), the date should be reset in today's date.

```
        public void DatePickerControl_ClearRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            editText.Text = string.Empty;
        }
```

Change to this:

```
        public void DatePickerControl_ClearRequested(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BirthdayDatePickerControl birthdayDate = sender as BirthdayDatePickerControl;
            birthdayDate.Date = DateTime.Now;
            editText.Text = "Birth Date";
        }
```

Comment: Hello sir, I tried your code but still I got an bad output. After hitting "register" button, the date today display in datepicker input which is 12/27/22 but when I click the date or calendar still the date is pointing in previous date were entered by customer. Supposedly, after clicking button, it will back to "birth date" placeholder.

Comment: @XamNewbie I don't quite understand what you described: `but when I click the date or calendar still the date is pointing in previous date were entered by customer. Supposedly, after clicking button, it will back to "birth date" placeholder. ` Could you provide some more relevant code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.

Comment: nothing codes change in my post sir,I just try your code. Im still finding if how to comment a picture so that you can visualize the code you commented.

Comment: [Try this sir if you can view what I want to express in my thread.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDjUI.png)

Comment: @XamNewbie I see what you mean. I update the answer, and it works. Wish it can help you.

Comment: Thank you sir, sorry for disturb cause I still newbie and beginner to xamarin, and your updated output works.

Comment: I already accepted or checked you answer sir because It helps me a lot and ofc for those who will encounter problem same as mine in the future, they can browse in the net and will apply your code. Gobdless sir.